# How to set stringname to class for generic <T>

Tags: delphi, generics

I want to Chnage the  from stringname. But I don't know if this is possibble.

Code I have:

```
function TServerMethods1.GetCustomer(aId: string): TJsonValue;
begin
  Result:=  ToJson(TRepositoryDatabase<TCustomer>.CreateRepository(Factories.FireBirdConnection.TFireBirdConnectionFactory.CreateConnecion(cConnectionString)).GetItem(aId));
end;
```

This works fine. 
But now I want to set the TCustomer as param.

```
function TServerMethods1.GetItem(aClassName, aId: string): TJsonValue;
var
  oClass: TClass;
  LCtx: TRttiContext;
  LTp: TRttiType;
begin
  try
    LTp := LCtx.FindType(AClassName);
  except
    Exit;
  end;

  if (LTp <> nil) and (LTp is TRttiInstanceType) then
    oClass := TRttiInstanceType(LTp).MetaclassType ;


  If assigned(oClass)
  then begin
    Result:=  ToJson(TRepositoryDatabase<oClass>.CreateRepository(Factories.FireBirdConnection.TFireBirdConnectionFactory.CreateConnecion(cConnectionString)).GetItem(aId));
  end;
end;
```

When I change the TCustomer with oClass I can't compile. 
I get [dcc32 Error] ServerMethodsUnit1.pas(115): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'TRepositoryDatabase'

```
 TRepositoryDatabase <T: Class> = class(TRepositoryBase <T>, IRepository<T>)
  private
    FManager: TObjectManager;
  public
    constructor Create(aConnection: IDBConnection);
    destructor Destroy; override;

    procedure SaveItem(aItem: T); override;
    function GetItem(Id: Variant): T; override;
    function GetItems: TList <T>; override;
    procedure DeleteItem(aItem: T); override;

    class function CreateRepository (aConnection: IDBConnection): IRepository <T>;

  end;
```

Is it possible to create a class from stringname and to set it in the generecs?

Comment: Unless you reference the generic type at compile time, the compiler won't instantiate that type. If you want runtime resolution then compile time generics is the wrong tool.

Comment: Thanks David, I was afraid of something like that.